# How to transform a DNAStringSet from the Bioconductor package Biostrings to a data frame?

Tags: r, bioconductor, format-conversion, biostrings

I am working on Mac OS X. I am using R version 3.5.1.

I have important a FASTA file into R using `Biostrings::readDNAStringSet`. This creates a DNAStringSet object in R.

I would like to transform it into a data frame so that I can then plot the widths with ggplot2.

`as.data.frame` on my DNAStringSet object returns a data frame with only one column. Is there a function that returns a data frame with columns `width`, `seq` and `names` present in the DNAStringSet object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation (`?Biostrings::DNAStringSet`):

> `width(x)`: A vector of non-negative integers containing the number of
>             letters for each element in `x`.  Note that `width(x)` is
>             also defined for a character vector with no NAs and is
>             equivalent to `nchar(x, type="bytes")`.
>
> `names(x)`: `NULL` or a character vector of the same length as `x`
>             containing a short user-provided description or comment for
>             each element in `x`.  These are the only data in an
>             XStringSet object that can safely be changed by the user. All
>             the other data are immutable!  As a general recommendation,
>             the user should never try to modify an object by accessing
>             its slots directly.
>
> `as.character(x, use.names=TRUE)`: Converts `x` to a character vector
>             of the same length as `x`.  The `use.names` argument controls
>             whether or not `names(x)` should be propagated to the names
>             of the returned vector.

This should be enough for you to create a `data.frame`:

`dss2df <- function(dss) data.frame(width=width(dss), seq=as.character(dss), names=names(dss))`

Also, if you have a huge `DNAStringSet`, perhaps you do not want to convert all the sequences to characters; storing sequences as characters supposedly is less efficient. For plotting it might be sufficient to have just widths.

`qplot(width(dss), geom='histogram'))`